# Horizontal list item with line between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to position a thin gray horizontal line between `<li>` elements on a horizontal navbar to provide connection perception between the elements. The code would be this below. How could I add a simple line between these elements?

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you say "between" do you mean that the line should be running through the middle of the characters themselves?

Comment: I've wanted to mean not through the elements, but side by side horizontally between elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a line running between each of the `li`s.

[image]

- Add `position: relative` to the `ul` so it becomes parent to `:after` element
- Position `:after` in the vertical middle of the characters using vertical translation
- Provide `z-index` and `background-color` to `li`s so they stay "on top of" of the gray line

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 0.75em;
    z-index: 1;
}

li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

ul:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, it is exactly how I thought.

Comment: how to make this list vertical

Comment: @PawanDeore Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lugz3nq/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a simple background coloration:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:linear-gradient(#ccc,#ccc)  center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size:25px;
}

li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And here is a way where you can have transparency:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) left  50px top 50%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) right 50px top 50%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) center;
  background-size:calc((100% - 4*50px)/3) 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50px;
  font-size:25px;
  text-align:center;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind centering the text on the navbar, this solution should work out for you.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch; /* Default */
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
  list-style-type: none;
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  border-right:1px solid gray;
}
li:last-of-type{
  border-right:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, jleggio. Actually it would be a horizontal line to provide the connection perception like Andy Hoffman wrote above

Answer (score -2):

I don't really understand the 'between' thing but you can add a:

```
li { border-left: 1px solid gray; border-right: 1px solid gray;
```

Like i said, not sure if this is what you mean. :)

Comment: If you are unsure what the question is about, then either ask for clarification (when you have 50 reputation) or just don't answer.